# How do I get the cache behind this grate on Marine HQ?

Tags: brutal-doom

On the Marine HQ level (level 5), there is a grate near the spawn where there is massive health crate and some item I've never seen before.  It's next to the red key card door.

Here is a screenshot below - it may be graphic due to the nature of the game hence why it's in the spoiler markup:

> [image: Cache]

I don't want to progress any further really in this level until I figure out how to access it since I'm very nearly dead.  How do you open this grate to get in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around the level for a hidden lever or button, I found nothing.

Slightly disappointed and annoyed, it came across my mind to attempt to blow the grate up with a rocket.  Sure enough, that worked. Usually, games like this have hidden buttons that open these types of areas, so I wasn't expecting it to be this simple.

> [image: Opened Cache]